# Search functionality using SWT Text

Tags: java, swt, jface

Im developing an SWT application which used JSCH api to download files from a server. There is an option to view the downloaded files in the application directly.

Im using a multi line text box which will display the file contents. Its all working till this point. Now i'm trying to add a search functionality which is going to have a new text box on top where user can enter the search keyword. The matching words should be highlighted in yellow background. I have used the code given in this link and its working

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/SearchStyleText.htm

But im running out of heap space very very fast. Can I implement the same kind of code on Text instead of StyledText.

Comment: Only StyledText supports varying colors. All Eclipse editors use StyledText and don't have heap space problems which suggests there is a problem in your code. Show us your code.

Comment: im sorry greg but i cannot share the code because of client restrictions. I can explain the workflow of the code. I hope it gives you a better understanding of what I did.

Comment: The problem is most likely to be leaking Fonts or Colors we can't see that from a description